# Query group results not returning all results?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

Since today I have been playing around with query groups for a small test I am running.

I have defined 2 groups in my query, 1 filters before a certain datetime, the other after the datetime. The following is a very simplified example of my groups setup.

```
group do
  query "before" do
    with(:planned).less_than mydate
  end
  query "after" do
    with(:planned).greater_than mydate
  end
end
```

After the query has been performed, I loop through my groups and I see the following results:

```
results.group(:queries).groups.each do |g|
  group_total = g.total
  group_results_count = g.results.count
end
```

query `before`:
`group_total` = 2
`group_results_count` = 1

query `after`:
`group_total` = 3
`group_results_count` = 1

The result count for my group is always 1. The **total** value is actually correct, I have double checked this through the Solr administration panel.

Am I misunderstanding something here, or do groups work differently from what I expect.

I am running on Solr 5.3.1

Answer (score 0):

By default Solr [returns one result for each group](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Result+Grouping) - see the `group.limit` parameter.

[According to the source](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/blob/964ecd0ed0a0c949f399d93cba42021c92cf6062/sunspot/lib/sunspot/query/group.rb), the grouping module in sunspot uses the limit argument:

```
  def to_params
    params = {
      :group            => "true",
      :"group.ngroups"  => "true",
    }

    params.merge!(@sort.to_params("group."))
    params[:"group.field"] = @fields.map(&:indexed_name) if @fields.any?
    params[:"group.query"] = @queries.map(&:to_boolean_phrase) if @queries.any?
    params[:"group.limit"] = @limit if @limit
    params[:"group.truncate"] = @truncate if @truncate

    params
  end
```